# Mongoose schema not efficient

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I have the following schema :

```
const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    companyName : {type: String , required : true}, 
    projectName : String, 

    revenueGroups : [{
        campMan : Number,
        startersPakket : Number, 
        marketingCon : Number, 
    }],

    revenueGroupsIn : [{
        campMan : Number,
        startersPakket : Number, 
        marketingCon : Number, 

    }],

    revenueGroupsSt : [{
        campMan : Number,
        startersPakket : Number, 
        marketingCon : Number, 

    }],

});
```

All the revenue groups are equal yet i have to repeat the process. Is there a more efficient way to doing this ?

Comment: It's just code; write a function that creates an array containing the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project.js

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    companyName : {type: String , required : true}, 
    projectName : String, 
    revenueGroups: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Revenue'}],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

revenue.js

```
var RevenueSchema = new Schema({
    campMan : Number,
    startersPakket : Number, 
    marketingCon : Number, 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Revenue', RevenueSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const revenueSchema = {
        campMan : Number,
        startersPakket : Number, 
        marketingCon : Number, 
    }

const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    companyName : {type: String , required : true}, 
    projectName : String, 

    revenueGroups : [revenueSchema],

    revenueGroupsIn : [revenueSchema],

    revenueGroupsSt : [revenueSchema],

});
```